# Texstudio Thesaurus is broken

Tags: latex, thesaurus

I just installed TeXStudio because I think it has more features than TeXmaker.

One thing I can't get to work is the thesaurus. I have [downloaded and installed a Danish thesaurus from LibreOffice](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/stavekontrolden-danish-dictionary/pscreleasefolder.2011-09-30.0280139318/2.1/dict-da-2.1.oxt) however it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried tex.stackexchange, but without luck. I think it's a bug, or a broken syntax in the .dat file from Libreoffice. What might be wrong with it?

Comment: Your question on tex.sx is still open and has valuable comments; please don't cross-post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a simpler way, just in case someone is still struggling with this problem. Just put into the synonyms dictionary path the LibreOffice location of the language you want to use. For example for the spanish language and windows OS use
 `"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\share\extensions\dict-es\th_es_ANY_v2.dat"`
and that's it. It works for me

Answer (score 18):

*(This answer is [extended with pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385157/how-to-set-up-thesaurus-in-texstudio#387327) in the TeX StackExchange)*.

By now you have surely solved the problem but for all the people that have the same trouble here is a tested solution **in any language**. :-)

There are two main steps in solving the problem:

1. Download the **Thesaurus files** (*.dat* and *.idx*)
2. Make *TexStudio* work with the **Thesaurus files**.

Here we go:

1. Download the Thesaurus Files

---

For me the easiest way to get those files is:

1. Download the LibreOffice/OpenOffice extension *.oxt* of your desired language's dictionary (check that the extension includes a **thesaurus** otherwise is useless! ;-))
   For instance for Danish the *.oxt* file can be found hier
   http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/stavekontrolden-danish-dictionary
2. Unzip the *.oxt* file and get both thesaurus files (*.dat* and *.idx*).  **Yes, you can** unzip a *.oxt* file! Use your favourite decompression program (e.g. LINUX: unzip, WINDOWS: winzip). On unziping you will see the files. For Danish the thesaurus files are:

- *th_da_DK.dat*
- *th_da_DK.idx*

3. Store the thesaurus files in your chosen folder. Now you can choose freely where to store them. My recommendation for LINUX: `/usr/share/mythes` but something like `~/mythesfolder` should also do.

You are ready with the download of the thesaurus files!

2. Make TexStudio work with the Thesaurus Files

---

To activate the **Thesaurus** in TexStudio:

1. Go to:  *Options -> Configure TexStudio -> General*
2. Now you are in a dialog with some sections: *Appearance*, *Dictionaries* and so on. You see in the section *Dictionaries* the field *Thesaurus Database*. Well, this is the nub of the matter you have to input in that field the full path of the *.dat* thesaurus file (in this step you can ignore the *.idx* file).
   Example: if you have installed the danish thesaurus on the path `/usr/share/mythes` you should write here
   `/usr/share/mythes/th_da_DK.dat`

**That's it!**

Comment: My apologies, LBJ - technical writing is an expectation here. "Small sentences of kindness" make a site into a chat-room, and Stack Overflow is not a chat-room. Meta discussion references are available on request.

Comment: I accept your apologies. Nevertheless I keep on thinking that to delete **just a short sentence** of kindness at the end of a long post an overshooting of the rule "make a site into a chat-room", even more, an intrusion into the freedom of expression in Stack Overflow (always kept in some boundaries). I will certainly bring the issue  on the meta stack. I am not a bot, giving correct answers: I am a human helping other humans. Be blessed!

Comment: When writing on this site, think of it like a journalist does writing for a newspaper - their work will be adjusted by an editor, and they don't think of their "free speech" being attenuated when that editor makes changes. It's normal here.

Comment: Meta sources: [about fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions), [about politeness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266525/being-polite-while-asking-a-question), [about thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333293/why-is-a-closing-thank-you-deemed-unprofessional). Here's [the Editing Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) in the Help Centre.

Comment: Thanks for the sources, I will take a look. (thumb up)